# Does flutter StreamProvider load all data on each app start

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app which load data from firebase using stream provider and listen to changes on the db.
my question is does the data is loaded from db every time the app start ? does it use caching ?

```
class LocalMain extends StatelessWidget {
 const LocalMain({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiProvider(
     providers: [
      StreamProvider<ConfigModel>(
        create: (_) => locator<ConfigModel>().fetchModelsAsStream()
```

Comment: Yes. It loads from db every time app starts.

Comment: That depends on how `locator<ConfigModel>().fetchModelsAsStream()` is implemented, which we can't see. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline, which documents Firestore's offline cache.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing this as a community wiki for others sake.

As mentioned by @Frank van Puffelen

> The behavior of `locator<ConfigModel\>().fetchModelsAsStream()` regarding caching is determined by its implementation, which we don't know from the provided code.

Firestore has an offline cache feature that stores data locally and synchronizes with the server when online. When using Firestore with StreamProvider, this cache can enhance performance and user experience by using cached data when available, reducing unnecessary network requests. If Firestore's offline cache is enabled, `locator<ConfigModel\>().fetchModelsAsStream()` will likely utilize the cached data when the app starts, improving efficiency. However, the specific implementation details and caching settings should be considered for desired behavior.

For more information about Firestore's offline cache please visit this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).